# Indie Feature Production and Post Production Audio Budgets

Tags: production-audio, post-production, rates, low-budget, budget

If you were asked to work post audio on a film, one man band style, and you knew the budget was $150,000, what would you think a fair price would be?  This is just for your services.  No dolby stuff or anything fancy, no music licensing, etc..., just your editing and mix.

On a similar note, what would you want to get paid for production audio?  My normal rate is $250 / day just for me to mix, plus $150 for the boom op, but I've had a ton of people with a $150k - $200k budget baulk at that.  Big production guys in the industry charge up to $1500 a day to mix (including gear) plus anywhere from $200 - $500 / day for the boom op, and $200 for an A2.

Just thinking about this for a project I have coming up, and this stuff was on my mind, having recently read that article that's been floating around on working for free.  Link anybody?

Thoughts?

Comment: My production rate is generally 350/day and most of the time + kit fee.  I've based this on what I am worth as a live concert engineer per day.  That same basis is how I am quoting people for hourly post work.  It is the conclusion of years of live engineering and what companies around here all seem comfortable in paying for my level of work.  I very rarely get anyone with a problem with that rate if they are an actual company and actual production.  Only the "investment" style of projects are what will try and talk me down.

Answer (score 11):

How about thinking of it from this angle?

1. You are effectively being asked to be an investor in the project, so cost it out at your normal rates & first give the producer that budget... Make them appreciate what it actually costs to do it 'properly' 
   call this total $A
2. Once they've recovered offer them an X% deferment option, so that you are not throwing away X%: that debt/investment will remain until it is paid, but you will have to be happy that you may never see the X% ever, so go into it resolved about this...

How to work out what X% is?

Add up your hard costs - if it will take you Y weeks to edit & prep it all & Z weeks to mix it, you are going to have to at least break even for Y+Z weeks, otherwise it is actually costing you money to work on the film... And will you turn down any full paying jobs during the Y+Z weeks? Or does the low budget project get done on weeks when you definitely have nothing on?

So add up (Y+Z) weeks of

- rent/mortgage payments (home + studio)
- electricity/phone/internet (home + studio)
- insurance (home + studio)
- transport
- food etc....

Total = $B

So ($A-$B)/$A = MAXIMUM possible % deferment/investment

And that should tell you whether you can actually do the project for what they offer....

I'm all for supporting projects that I love and/or dear friends, but if you are going to commit to it for 2 or 3 months, you shouldn't end up personally in debt for it

(I dont do production sound so cant help with shoot side of it all)

Comment: I've always hated math, but this formula is definitely an exception. Fantastic post.

Answer (score 6):

I had also posted this question over at Gearslutz in the Post Production forum.  Here's a great answer from "Big Andy".

> I am doing a 90 minute film for a
>   friend in a couple weeks that is only
>   dialogue, BGs and Music with a similar
>   budget and I'm still making my union
>   base for all editorial and dubbing
>   plus DNS One as a perk.
>
> VERY MINIMUM you should take on a
>   $100k project is $15k [IMO]. In truth,
>   the amount of work, time spent
>   finagling once the director decides
>   the crickets sound too Blue, and
>   relationship strain that you will be
>   dealing with is not worth anything
>   less. I've done plenty of "one man
>   band" projects and if you aren't VERY
>   STRICT with your clients, you'll end
>   up working for less than $10 / hr.
>
> The "Rule" or guideline is that post
>   sound gets between 2-5% of the budget.
>   But that is assuming it is a film with
>   a budget. If the producer is at all
>   experienced s/he will know what the
>   real costs of post sound are and will
>   hopefully plan the production with at
>   least a base cost sound budget. If
>   they don't know what the costs are,
>   PLEASE let them know. Everything from
>   your electricity, insurance, paper,
>   DVDs and whatever else.
>
> Most sound packages I build for
>   clients are six figures and even with
>   those numbers, things run tight a lot
>   of the time. Figure out what your
>   studio's operating costs are... figure
>   out what you need to live on and then
>   figure in a profit margin as well as
>   pay yourself to look for a new job
>   once the current one is over.

Answer (score 3):

General starting point for me is 10% of the total budget, it's never that simple though. Depends on how confident I am that I'll get the project and how demanding it is.  Also, what kind of mix environment I can package for the client seems to make a big difference in how much I can charge.

Comment: BTW I rarely get 10%.

Answer (score 0):

doing a 20k feature. everyone worked minimum wage on set to get the film to actually happen so about 750 for 3 weeks. now i'm doing post sound i'm going to be very busy but not sure what is a fair asking price. 10% as suggested about would be 2000, which is out of the question. I would think another 750 just to make the film a reality but their funds are really tight. a point in the profits is included but who knows what will happen.